# FPSCounter is not recognised and can't be used

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, frame-rate, flame

I wanted to see if I could add a FPSCounter to a Flutter Flame app and the official documentation shows it to just be added after FlameGame.

This is what the official documentation shows:

```
class MyGame extends FlameGame with FPSCounter {
  static final fpsTextConfig = TextConfig(color: BasicPalette.white.color);

  @override
  void render(Canvas canvas) {
    super.render(canvas);
    final fpsCount = fps(120); // The average FPS for the last 120 microseconds.
    fpsTextConfig.render(canvas, fpsCount.toString(), Vector2(0, 50));
  }
}
```

I've tried adding it as well in the same way, this is my code:

```
import 'package:flame/events.dart';
import 'package:flame/game.dart';
import 'package:flame/flame.dart';
import 'package:flame/input.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Flame.device.fullScreen();

  runApp(
      GameWidget(
          game: MyGame()
      )
  );
}

class MyGame extends FlameGame with TapDetector, FPSCounter {
  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    super.onLoad();
    print('<game loop> onLoad() called');
  }
  
  @override
  void update(double dt) {
    super.update(dt);
    // print('<game loop> update called at delate time $dt');
  }
  
  @override
  void render(Canvas canvas) {
    super.render(canvas);
    
    canvas.drawPaint(Paint()..color = Colors.red);

    // print('<game loop> render called');
  }

  @override
  void onTapUp(TapUpInfo info) {
    // print('game loop onTap location: (${info.eventPosition.game.x}, ${info.eventPosition.game.y})');
  }
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
lib/main.dart:19:50: Error: Type 'FPSCounter' not found.
class MyGame extends FlameGame with TapDetector, FPSCounter {
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^
```

There don't seem to be any dependencies that need to be resolved, I've done it several times and it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you use a newer version of flame and your sample is from the old documentation:

https://docs.flame-engine.org/1.0.0/debug.html

On the top of the documentation you also see a warning:

[image]

Here is the new documentation: https://docs.flame-engine.org/latest/flame/other/debug.html#fps

And a working example: https://github.com/flame-engine/flame/blob/main/examples/lib/stories/components/debug_example.dart